# Calling Objective-C method with blocks from Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, objective-c-blocks

I have a method in `Objective-C` as follows:

```
- (void)myFunction:(void (^)(NSArray *data))successBlock error:(void (^)(NSError *error))errorBlock {
    //...//
    successBlock(someData);
}
```

I want to call it from `Swift`, but I can't understand the syntax.

Whatever I try it complains:

```
SomeClass.sharedInstance().myFunction(
    successBlock: {
        (data) in
        print(data)
    },
    error: {
        (error) in
        print(error)
    })
```

Cannot call value of non-function type

> '(((([AnyObject]!) -> Void!, error: ((NSError!) -> Void)!) -> Void)!

Comment: The code completion is supposed to suggest you the proper syntax

Comment: If I autocomplete the suggestion Xcode gives me it fails with the same error

Answer (score 1):

This Swift equivalent is

```
SomeClass.sharedInstance().myFunction({ data in
     print(data) 
   }) { error in 
     print(error) 
   }
```

If you need the parameter names `successBlock`and `errorBlock` you have to declare them on the ObjC side.